# RouterOS 6.27 Port Forwarding from inner network to inner network (hairpin NAT)

Tags: mikrotik-routeros

Anyone had issues with accessing webserver from local using RouterOS with 6.27 Firmware?  I had everything working fine until upgrade to 6.27.

In addition, Hairpin NAT does not work.

Comment: Can you add more information to your question? What stopped working correctly? Have you tried to revert back to 6.26?

Answer (score 0):

The key to the issue is that `dstnat` is processed earlier than `srcnat`. If a data has passed through `dstnat`, then, and only then `srcnat rules will work.

Here is the config that makes Hairpin NAT to work:

```
/ip firewall nat> print
Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid, D - dynamic
 0    ;;; Hairpin NAT
      chain=srcnat action=masquerade protocol=tcp src-address=192.168.0.0/24
      dst-address=192.168.0.0/24 out-interface=bridge-local log=no log-prefix=""

 1    ;;; NAT masquerade for outgoing connections
      chain=srcnat action=masquerade out-interface=ether1-gateway log=no log-prefix=""

 2    ;;; HTTP
      chain=dstnat action=netmap to-addresses=192.168.0.150 to-ports=80 protocol=tcp
  dst-address=76.35.222.205 dst-address-type=local dst-port=81 log=no log-prefix=""
```

`76.35.222.205` is a fake address representing my external IP address. I tried to work without it, but experience a several seconds delay when using Hairpin NAT.

- Rule 0 makes sure that response is returned to inner machine sent a request.
- Rule 1 is a conventional NAT masquerade which is used with or without Hairpin NAT
- Rule 2 is port forwarding regardless from where the connection has been initiated.

When requesting a local HTTP server from inside, the rule 2 works as first, then the rule 0.

It may also be that something is wrong in your Filter rules.